# Is there any good books of Algebra containing Group action topics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, book-recommendation, group-actions

Is there any  good  books  of Algebra containing **Group action** topics?

I have Dummit and Foote book  but I'm not satisfied and I feel like I didn't learn anything because Dummit Foote didn't explain in detail. No doubts this book contains lot of good exercises

Comment: Knapp's "Basic Algebra" has a long section on group actions. For a more categorical take, you might look at Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0". It contains a lot of discussion of group actions in context, but it's a bit more scattered through the text than Knapp, which might make it a bit more annoying to reference.

Comment: You might also want an early book on "geometric group theory", such as Meier's "Groups, Graphs, and Trees". This (excellent) little book is all about group actions, in particular about groups acting on geometric objects. It's also quite readable.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks u